# Ajax загрузка сайта

Tags: ajax

Как сделать подобную загрузку страниц?
Чтоб инлдикатор загрузки был, и страница полностью не перезагружалась.
Пример: http://web.odin-odin.ru/#portfolio/aromavis.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кроме прочих настроек ajax-запроса, добавляете **beforeSend** (содержит функцию, которая будет выполнена перед запросом) и **complete** (функция, которая будет вызвана после завершения ajax-запроса). В первой функции вы убираете текущий контент любым понравившимся способом и выводите на экран блок с прелоадером, во второй функции - обратные действия. Вот примерная реализация:

```
var contentBlock =$('#container'); // блок контента страницы
var preloader = $('#preloader_block'); // блок прелоадера
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'handler.php',
    data: {pageId: idVal},
    beforeSend: function(){
        contentBlock.animate({opacity: 0});
        preloader.show().animate({opacity: 1});
    },
    complete: function(){
        contentBlock.animate({opacity: 1});
        preloader.animate({opacity: 0}).hide();
    }
    success: function(data){
        contentBlock.html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы при клике по ссылкам яакс срабатывал?

Comment: Однозначно тут не ответишь. Но если снова на примитивном примере, то примерно так:

    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // тут код ajax-запроса
    });

Кроме того, что вам надо будет точно указать селектор ссылок (какой-нибудь класс) вместо примитивного $('a'), вам еще надо подумать о том, как получать тот же id требуемой страницы. Как варианты, можно из тега <a> вытаскивать значение **href** или дописать в каждую ссылку атрибут **data-id="тут_id_страницы"**, или какой-нибудь другой способ. Тут надо смотреть по ситуации.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы еще и история была (стрелки "вперед" и "назад") ?

Comment: [HTML5-History-API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API)

Comment: URL меняется, но данные не обновляются при прогулке по кнопкам "Назад" и "Вперед". Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @vinnie, не лентяйничайте, сударь )) По ссылке, которую я дал выше, внизу страницы, есть описание на русском, есть демка и примеры реализации как на jQuery, так и на чистом JS